# IPv6 multicast regular expression in JS example?

Tags: ipv6, multicast

I find out the regular expression to check the "ipv6".

is there any regular expression for  the "ipv6  multicast"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check that the IPv6 address is valid, and located in the `ff00::/8` network ([RFC 4291 § 2.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.7)). An address matching both criteria is a valid multicast address.

Comment: If the address is valid, then to check for multicast splitting the address around `:` and matching the first part using `/^([fF]{2}[0-9a-fA-F]{2})$/` works.